# Laravel calculating previous and next recurring date

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, laravel

I am in the process of setting up a recurring event model e.g.

```
event: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'event name',
    date: '2017-04-22', // First occurrence of the event
    frequency: 'weekly'
}
```

The goal is to be able to calculate the previous and next occurrence of the event based on a given date e.g.

```
getLastOccurrance('2017-06-29') // Would return '2017-06-24'
getNextOccurrance('2017-06-29') // Would return '2017-07-01'
```

Would be awesome if I could somehow return the previous and next date in an eloquent query with the event. Something like:

```
event: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'event name',
    date: '2017-04-22',
    frequency: 'weekly',
    last_event: '2017-06-24',
    next_event: '2017-07-01'
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, I may be going about things completely wrong. Hopefully I have explained the desired result well enough. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using php's DateInterval and DatePeriod functions to get an array of dates. Here's an example:

```
  $start      = new DateTime( '2018-08-01' ); // Date to increment from
  $end        = new DateTime( '2018-10-01' ); // Date to increment up to
  $interval   = new DateInterval("P2D"); // The increment interval, 2 days
  $days       = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

  foreach($days as $day)...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Carbon,

```
$next_event = Carbon::parse('2017-04-22')->addDays(7);
$last_event = Carbon::parse('2017-04-22')->addDays(-7);
```

You can use `addWeeks` function as well like: `addWeeks(1)` and `addWeeks(-1)`

Comment: Would that not just give me the week before and after of the original date? Im looking to pass any date, and return the previous and next occurrence of the event.

Comment: What do you want ? two functions to get last and next week dates ?

Comment: @patskot were you successful at this? Could you share an example of how you finally went about it

Comment: Hi @TumainiMosha, I've gone ahead and added an answer for this one. See above.